# meaning of 'call to aid your fancy'

Tags: meaning-in-context

“Well then, Jane, **call to aid your fancy**:—suppose you were no longer a girl well reared and disciplined, but a wild boy indulged from childhood upwards; imagine yourself in a remote foreign land. . .” (Jane Eyre)

What’s the meaning of ‘call’ in the highlighted part? Does it mean ‘come to aid your fancy’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Now, my little friend, while the sun drinks the dew--while all the
>   flowers in this old garden awake and expand, and the birds fetch
>   their young ones' breakfast out of the Thornfield, and the early
>   bees do their first spell of work--I'll put a case to you, which you
>   must endeavour to suppose your own: but first, look at me, and tell
>   me you are at ease, and not fearing that I err in detaining you, or
>   that you err in staying."
>
> "No, sir; I am content."
>
> "Well then, Jane, call to aid your fancy:- suppose you were no
>   longer a girl well reared and disciplined, but a wild boy indulged
>   from childhood upwards; imagine yourself in a remote foreign land;
>   conceive that you there commit a capital error, no matter of what
>   nature or from what motives, but one whose consequences must follow
>   you through life and taint all your existence.

I read this as "Now try to use your imagination"

[fancy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fancy)

> a mental image or conception: He had happy fancies of being a famous actor.

I am not the only one to think so: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2605963
Also yours I believe...